# How to improve the Tensorflow official transformer accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

every one:

I just run the [transformer in Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer) with Google Colaboratory. After 20 epoch training, I got the model performance in :

```
Epoch 20 Batch 700 Loss 0.5509 Accuracy 0.3449
Saving checkpoint for epoch 20 at ./checkpoints/train/ckpt-4
Epoch 20 Loss 0.5510 Accuracy 0.3449
Time taken for 1 epoch: 63.83616662025452 secs
```

Why is the accuracy so low ? And how can I improve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can train the model for 100 epochs to improve the accuracy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).